# Tokio-based program produces results but then hangs before cleanup

Tags: rust, async-await, rust-tokio

I am attempting to write a basic Rust client for [HackerNews](https://news.ycombinator.com/) that fetches the titles for the top 500 stories using their [API](https://github.com/HackerNews/API/blob/master/README.md). The minimum reproduction code is below:

src/main.rs:

```rust
use futures::future::join_all;

const BASE_URL: &str = "https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0";

#[tokio::main(flavor = "multi_thread", worker_threads = 10)]
async fn main() {
    let client = reqwest::Client::new();

    // Get the ids for all the current top stories.
    let top_stories_ids: Vec<i32> = client
        .get(format!("{}/topstories.json", BASE_URL))
        .send()
        .await
        .unwrap()
        .json::<Vec<i32>>()
        .await
        .unwrap();

    // Gather a list of futures to be used to get each individual item from the top stories.
    let top_stories_items_futures: Vec<_> = top_stories_ids
        .into_iter()
        .map(|id| client.get(format!("{}/item/{}.json", BASE_URL, id)).send())
        .collect();

    // Make all the network calls and collect futures for extracting the json responses.
    let top_stories_json_futures: Vec<_> = join_all(top_stories_items_futures)
        .await
        .into_iter()
        .map(|resp| resp.unwrap().json::<serde_json::Value>())
        .collect();

    // Do all the json response extractions and print all the post titles.
    let top_stories_items: Vec<_> = join_all(top_stories_json_futures)
        .await
        .into_iter()
        .filter_map(|json| json.ok())
        .collect();
    for story in &top_stories_items {
        println!("{:?}", story["title"]);
    }
}
```

Cargo dependencies:

```ini
futures = "0.3.28"
reqwest = { version = "0.11.18", features = ["json", "rustls-tls"] }
serde = { version = "1.0.166", features = ["derive"] }
serde_json = "1.0.100"
tokio = { version = "1.29.1", features = ["macros", "rt-multi-thread"] }
```

The problem is that, while the top 500 post titles are successfully printed to the console quite quickly (under a second), the program will then hang for 10-15 seconds afterwards before finally finishing and yielding control back to the shell. This hang makes it seem as though the program is lagging, even though all of the real work has already successfully completed.

What could be causing this? I am a novice when it comes to Rust async/await, but this behavior seems to me like it's due to the tokio runtime doing some kind of task cleanup before shutting down the program. If so, why is it taking so long and is there anything I can do to mitigate this? I can add something like `std::process::exit(0)` at the end and this hang goes away, but this feels dirty and I'd rather know if I'm misunderstanding something important about how these async runtimes function.

Comment: I couldn't reproduce this, but note that if you use `spawn_blocking`, the runtime has to wait for the task to finish (if it's been started) before the runtime can drop. This is most apparent when you try to read from [tokio's stdin](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/io/fn.stdin.html), since tokio internally does `spawn_blocking`. The runtime doesn't know that it's being dropped at the end of `main`, so it can't ignore the running task, but you know it, so calling `exit` is technically fine, just kind of ugly.

Comment: Thanks for trying, weird that you couldn't reproduce the issue. How do I check whether `spawn_blocking` is being used (either in the runtime or in the `join_all()` calls)? Also, as far as I know all the tasks finish quickly, as the final results are displayed within a second, so I'm not sure what the runtime would be waiting for at that point. I suppose for now I can call `exit` myself, though it does feel a bit wrong.

Comment: No idea if it will provide relevant information, but you can try using [tokio-console](https://github.com/tokio-rs/console).